# Is there a way to get name of child class in parent class?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print out the name of class B or C in it's super class (A). Is there a way to infer this somehow from the context? Do I have to pass in the names into super as a parameter or is there a better way of doing this?

```
class A {
  constructor(){
    console.log(klass_name) // klass_name is some code to get the name of class B,C
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

class c extends A {
  super();
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways you can access it where you've shown:

- `this.constructor.name` (assuming nothing has messed around with it), which you can use anywhere that has access to the instance
- `new.target.name` (only available in the constructor, `new.target` is `undefined` in function calls that aren't part of a `new` operation)

But other than logging purposes and such, it's rare for the superclass to need to know anything about the subclass.

Example:

```js
class A {
  constructor(){
    console.log("this.constructor.name = " + this.constructor.name);
    console.log("new.target.name = " + new.target.name);
  }
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends A {
}

new C;
```

The `constructor` property is automatically set up on a class's prototype to refer to the class's constructor, and as of ES2015 functions (including constructors) have a `name` property on them giving their name. Since the instance inherits from the prototype, you can use `constructor` on it to access that constructor and its `name`.

The [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) metaproperty is available in functions to indicate what the target function of the `new` expression was.

---

Side note: When your subclass constructor is nothing but a call to the superclass constructor, you can leave it off entirely. The JavaScript engine will add one for you.

Comment: `this.constructor.name` works perfectly. I need the base class in my scenario, just simplified for post. Thx

Comment: I want to get the name of the child class in static method of parent class

Comment: @AmarjitSingh - I suggest posting a question with code demonstrating the problem. Depending on how the static method is called, though, you can do that with `this.name` (since the way static methods are usually called means `this` refers to the constructor function): http://jsfiddle.net/5f1rxme4/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Here is the link to my question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529306

There is also a similar question But that is for PHP.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391542

Answer (score 1):

An instance can get a hold of its constructor function via `this.constructor`. The name of the function is available as the property `.name`. So, it's surprisingly straight forward:

```
console.log(this.constructor.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.constructor.name
```

Should do the trick.